# Android: Detect back button release

Tags: android

I am able to detect when the back button is pressed by using:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do my thing
}
```

But now I want to detect when the back button is released. How can I do that? I'm unable to find any method like `onBackReleased()` which I can override to do my thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no method that specifically detects the back button release, but you could use the `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` methods. Check to make sure the key is the back button, and do your stuff in the method. Here is something you could do:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do your stuff for when the back button is initially pressed
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do your stuff for when the back button is released
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to override the default back press, you could just use the `onBackPressed()` method, like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Prevents the user from clicking the back button and returning to the parent activity
}
```

These methods can be implemented directly in your class. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do these methods override the default behavior? I mean when I would press the back button, will the previous activity be opened as well?

Comment: No, these methods do not override the default behavior. But if you wanted to do that, you could just override the `onBackPressed()` method. Check my edit for more info.

Comment: Yes or I could just use `dispatchKeyEvent`.

Comment: Yes, you could very well do that. Glad I helped!